# How to disable a Combobox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

Basically, I want to disable a certain Combobox, based on the value of another combobox.
I couldn't find a answer to this question, maybe because it's very uncommon to do this to a Combobox.

I have a code more or less as follow...

```
    self.cBox1Var=tki.StringVar()
    self.cBox1=ttk.Combobox(self.mframe, width=16, textvariable=self.cBox1Var, state='readonly',values=['Text entry','Combo box','Check button'])
    self.cBox1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tki.W)
    self.cBox1Var.set('Text entry')
    self.cBox1Var.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, count=count: self.EnableDisableParamFields(event, count))

    self.cBox2Var=tki.StringVar()
    self.cBox2=ttk.Combobox(self.mframe, width=16, textvariable=self.cBox2Var, state='readonly',values=['String','Integer','Float'])
    self.cBox2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=tki.W)
    self.cBox2Var.set('String')
```

...

```
def EnableDisableParamFields(self, event, count):
    if self.cBox1Var.get()=='Combo box':  #disable 'Entry format combo box'
        #disable "self.cBox2"
    else:
        #enable "self.cBox2"
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT!!!!**

After persisting, found the answer, and it is quite simple. 
For those who may be interested, the solution can be found here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm

"state='disabled', 'readonly' or 'normal' "

Comment: BWT: You can even hide widget - with `.grid_forget()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use the `Combobox` option of `state='disabled'`.

There are three options for `state` as follows:

- `state='normal'` which is the fully functional `Combobox`.
- `state='readonly'` which is the `Combobox` with a value, but can't be changed (directly).
- `state='disabled'` which is where the `Combobox` cannot be interacted with.